# Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier when try to show window for printing

Tags: javascript

I am getting an "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier" when try to show window for printing. It works fine locally, but when I deploy it to an Ubuntu server, the error shows up.

```
function PrintDiv() {
    var divToPrint = document.getElementById('divToPrint');
    var site="<html lang='en'><body onload='window.print()'>" + divToPrint.innerHTML + "</html>";
    var popupWindow = window.open('', '_blank', 'width=800,height=900');
    popupWindow.document.write(site);
    popupWindow.document.close();
}
```

And I am calling the div like this to display what I am printing.

```
<div id="divToPrint" style="display:none;">
<div style="width:700px;height:900px;">
    <h1 align="center">Active Accounts</h1>
    <table border="1" align="center" width="100%">
        <tr>
            <th>Account ID</th>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Type</th>
            <th>Phone</th>
            <th>Address</th>
        </tr>
        <?php foreach($accounts as $account) : ?>
            <tr>
                <td><?php print $account->get_id(); ?></td>
                <td><?php print $account->get_name(); ?></td>
                <td><?php print $account->map_attribute_type(); ?></td>
                <td><?php print $account->get_phone_number(); ?></td>
                <td><?php print $account->get_address()->get_string(); ?></td>
            </tr>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
    </table>

</div>
```

```
<input class="small button" type="button" value="print" onclick="PrintDiv();" />
```

Comment: Could you please provide a little more context? How do you call this function, what's inside `divToPrint` element, at what line the error happens?

Comment: I updated the question with how I am calling the function.

Comment: I don't see the function call.

Comment: I created a codepen based on your code, works fine: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/LXKmpq

Comment: Sorry missed a line, added the function

Comment: Try using `htmlspecialcharacters` on the values you are dynamically printing in PHP.

Comment: The debugger in the browser's Developer Tools should point you to the place where the syntax error is occurring.

Comment: It says this line is the problem -->     var site="<html lang='en'><body onload='window.print()'>" + divToPrint.innerHTML + "</html>";

Comment: Demo with the button works fine: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/LXKmpq
Please provide the output from developer tools console. It might be caused by something else.